# replace with 0 duplicate variable according to ID

Tags: r, dplyr, replace, duplicates

I have a dataframe like this one:

```
df
ID  job_code
1   8
1   8
1   8
2   7
2   7
2   4
3   1
3   2
```

If an individual has several times the same job code, I would like to keep only the first one and replace the others by 0, to obtain a dataframe like this one:

```
df
ID  job_code    job_code_2
1   8           8
1   8           0
1   8           0
2   7           7
2   7           0
2   4           4
3   1           1
3   2           2
```

I thought of using function :

```
dataframe %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  and replace
```

but I am not sure how.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L),
  job_code = c(8L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 1L, 2L)
)

df %>%
  group_by(ID, job_code) %>%
  mutate(job_code2 = job_code * +(row_number() == 1)) %>%
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 8 x 3
#>      ID job_code job_code2
#>   <int>    <int>     <int>
#> 1     1        8         8
#> 2     1        8         0
#> 3     1        8         0
#> 4     2        7         7
#> 5     2        7         0
#> 6     2        4         4
#> 7     3        1         1
#> 8     3        2         2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I get this error message : Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `job_code2 = job_code* +(row_number() == 1)`.
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: ID = 1.
Caused by error in `job_code * +(row_number() == 1)`:
! non-numerical argument for a binary operator
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: show a small reproducible example of data with this error

Comment: I restarted my whole R session and finally it worked, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Great! If you believe this answer was helpful for you, you could accept it by clicking the tick on the left side of this answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `duplicated`:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(job_code2 = ifelse(duplicated(job_code), 0, job_code)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

in base R you can use `tapply` + `duplicated`:

```
df$job_code2 <- unlist(tapply(df$job_code, df$ID, function(x) ifelse(duplicated(x), 0, x)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- read_table("ID  job_code
1   8
1   8
1   8
2   7
2   7
2   4
3   1
3   2")

df %>% 
  group_by(ID, job_code) %>% 
  mutate(job_code = if_else(row_number() > 1, 0, job_code)) %>% 
  ungroup

#> # A tibble: 8 x 2
#>      ID job_code
#>   <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1     1        8
#> 2     1        0
#> 3     1        0
#> 4     2        7
#> 5     2        0
#> 6     2        4
#> 7     3        1
#> 8     3        2
```

Answer (score 0):

the first function is good but I don't know why there are some subjects where it doesn't work. For subjects where there is already a code that has been released for a previous subject it doesn't work
for example, for subject 4 I get a 0 when I should get an 8

I have this :

ID  job_code    job_code_2
1   8           8
1   8           0
1   8           0
2   7           7
2   7           0
2   4           4
3   1           1
3   2           2
4   8           0

Instead of this :

ID  job_code    job_code_2
1   8           8
1   8           0
1   8           0
2   7           7
2   7           0
2   4           4
3   1           1
3   2           2
4   8           8

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).